# Retry loop for asynchronous HTTP requests

Tags: c#, exception-handling, http, async-await

I've got a method that needs to PUT data to a web API. Sometimes the connection fails, so I needed a way to do retries, but if the retries fail, I still need to capture the exception and re-throw it.

I've got something that I "believe" is working, but I've got a stupid throw at the end. Is there a better, more concise way to do this when working with async tasks?

```
private const int TotalNumberOfAttempts = 10;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutWithRetriesAsync(string url,
    HttpContent content,
    AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeaderValue,
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue mediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue)
{
    var numberOfAttempts = 0;
    ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            return await PutAsync(url, content, authenticationHeaderValue, mediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
            numberOfAttempts++;
        }
    } while (numberOfAttempts < TotalNumberOfAttempts);

    if (capturedException != null)
    {
        capturedException.Throw();
    }
    throw new Exception("That will never be thrown");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite your code into a `while (true)` loop, that can only be exited using the `return` in your `try` or using a `throw;` inside a condition in your `catch`:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        return await PutAsync(url, content, authenticationHeaderValue, mediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue);
    }
    catch
    {
        numberOfAttempts++;
        if (numberOfAttempts >= TotalNumberOfAttempts)
            throw;
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need `ExceptionDispatchInfo` or the useless  (but required by the compiler) `throw` at the end.

I also changed `catch (AggregateException ex)` to catch all exceptions, because `await` usually doesn't throw `AggregateException` (unlike `task.Wait()` or `task.Result`).

Comment: This is a good approach. I had originally done the same thing with a `do`, but without the ExceptionDispatchInfo. I was just under the impression that the EDI was the right way to deal with `async` exceptions.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell If you need to catch it in one place and then rethrow it somewhere else, yes. But you don't need to do that here, `throw;` will work as well and it's simpler.

Comment: ah, makes sense. So this approach is equally as valid. https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/9524b2e8a85dfa5b563e

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Not really, `throw ex;` on an exception that you caught will overwrite the stack trace of the exception. The entire point of EDI is to avoid that. So, you should use just `throw;` when you can. And when you can't, use EDI, but don't rethrow an exception using `throw ex;`.

Comment: makes perfect sense.

Comment: I did change the `Exception ex` to just `Exception`, since we're not doing anything with ex.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell You're right, though you can simplify that even more (see edit).

Comment: Sorry but what does EDI mean?

Comment: @Ozkan It's short for `ExceptionDispatchInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
private const int TotalNumberOfAttempts = 10;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutWithRetriesAsync(string url,
    HttpContent content,
    AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeaderValue,
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue mediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    for(int i = 0; i < TotalNumberOfAttempts; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return await PutAsync(url, content, authenticationHeaderValue, mediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    } 
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

You can easily abstract this functionality into an extension method to provide retry logic for any arbitrary `Func<Task>`.

Comment: Why are you rethrowing all of the exceptions? I doubt they will give you any additional information, rethrowing just the last one should be enough.

Comment: This kind of retry logic is very dangerous and is rarely a good idea. The nature of the connectivity/network failure OP is up against will determine whether or not retry logic makes sense here and what to do with the exceptions he accumulates.